Android Login to OAuth2 client
I have a Spring server which acts as an API gateway for some microservices. The way I handle login is by using Keycloak as a IAM, and the Gateway as an OAuth2 Client with authentication code flow. Now when I need to login using a web application it's all simple and easy with the various redirections that gets performed. I also have an Android application that I would to link to this system, I saw some guides they where all getting the token (the web application just uses the sessions and not the token), I do not wont that. Is there a way to keep the session? Or it should be done via AuthenticationManager?

This is how the application.yaml of the API Gateway is configured
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${ISSUER_URI:http://keycloak:8080/realms/crm}
        registration:
          gateway-client:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope:
              - openid
              - offline_access
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: ${REDIRECT_URI:http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/gateway-client}



Even if it's the right way to go, there are difficulties in securing a mobile application with sessions and using authorization code flow:

not all mobile user agents handle cookies out of the box like browsers do
very few mobile frameworks handle cookie-based protection against CSRF for you (read the XSRF-TOKEN cookie value and set it as X-XSRF-TOKEN header to POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE requests like Angular does for instance)
you have to switch between user agents (app internal HTTP client and browser) at different steps of the authorization code flow

The first two points are rather trivial to implement by yourself. Just be careful to respect the secure and same-site flags before attaching a cookie to a request. Also, be very careful
where you store cookies (keeping it only in memory is probably a good option).
The last point is a little more tricky. You need to:

Change the status of redirections from your Spring client to the authorization server:  from 302 to something in the 2xx range, for your mobile app code to be able to intercept it and switch to the system browser for user login on the authorization server. I wrote a Spring Boot starter which, among other things, allows configuring authorization code responses status from just properties.
Deep linking, to switch back from the browser to the app when the authorization server answers with the authorization code: you need to forward the code using the app internal client with the session cookie for the tokens to be stored in the gateway session dedicated to the mobile app internal HTTP client.

Note that even if creating proper Android App Link ("verified") is no more simple than iOS Universal Link (you need a website on which to publish domain ownership verification data), it is necessary as soon as you use OAuth2 authorization code flow, tokens being handled by the mobile app or a BFF. When the authorization server redirects with the authorization code after successful login:

in the case of a mobile app configured as a public OAuth2 client, you need to switch back from the browser to the app to provide it with the code so that it can do its OAuth2 client job and exchange the code for tokens
in the case of a BFF, you need to forward the code with the app internal HTTP client so that the session cookie is attached to the request (and the BFF knows in which session to store the tokens, as written above already).


So basically you are advising me not use sessions because they are too complicated to handle both on Android and on the Gateway. Let's say I do get the token from Keyclock on my app, how do I go through the Gateway? Is there an option to accept both sessions and tokens in yaml file?

My 1st sentence contains it's the right way to go. Also, why do you think I maintain a starter with configuration options to do this? And why do you think I know all the details of an implementation if it wasn't a solution I apply already? So yes, I advise to use sessions: even if it is more work than configuring the mobile app as a public client (with an OAuth2 client lib for the framework you're using and a second set of routes on the gateway without the TokenRelay filter), it is still feasible and a safer solution.

Also, you'll need deep linking too in the option where the mobile app is a public client: this doesn't change the need to switch to the system browser during user login on the authorization server and then back to the app when the authorization code is returned. In that case the app uses the code itself to get tokens, instead to forwarding it to the BFF. So this is a rather boring step you'll need in any case: creating proper Android App Link ("verified") is no more simple than iOS Universal Link (you need a website on which to publish domain ownership verification data) .
